# Civicrm, how to export contacts with custom fields?

Tags: drupal-7, civicrm

I'm use CIVICRM with drupal, i want to export all individual contacts with its custom field data, when I tried with admin panel to export data but there custom fields data missing,

can any one know how its solve?

Comment: there's a proposal to create a CiviCRM StackExchange community. While we're well over minimum of 'committers' needed to launch, we're still well shy of 100 people who have been active enough on other StackExchange sites to earn 200 reputation. Any chance you could help yourself and us out? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "Select fields for export" (not the default "Export PRIMARY fields"). If, for example, you created a field named "Organization 2" under a profile called "Profile", it would be listed as "Profile: Organization 2" in your field list.

Comment: Heh @Northside Collaborative, any chance you could support a CiviCRM StackExchange site by committing to participate at area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm ? Cheers!